# What is the difference between Dynamic Array and Dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

According to Wikipedia page on dynamic array, they're not the same thing.
[Wiki page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)
How is  the memory allocation in both the array work, what we need to keep in mind while using either of them and which one to prefer.
P.S. : I'm new to programming

Comment: From your link: "*A dynamic array is not the same thing as a dynamically allocated array, which is an array whose size is fixed when the array is allocated, although a dynamic array may use such a fixed-size array as a back end.*" What did you not understand about this sentence? It's hard to explain something to you if you don't say what you don't understand.

Comment: I have tried to post my query more elaboratly, now

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic array is an abstract datatype that have almost the same API as static arrays but it uses dynamically allocated arrays internally.

The list in Python is an example of a dynamic array; the arrays in C are static arrays, but the language enables you to dynamically allocate an array at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic array is similar to an array but it's size is dynamic and so it will grab more memory when it is full and you add a new element to it. They can be created on the stack or on the heap.

A dynamically allocated array is simply an array that is created on the heap.

Comment: Can u elaborate on the point "grab more memory when it is full"

Comment: So for the dynamic array, you initially set a size, say N elements. Then after filling in all N elements, if you try to add another then it will reallocate memory for the array to now accomodate N+1 elements. Essentially it will grow if you add more elements than it has allocated space for.

Answer (score 0):

So, now it is more than 5 years after publishing this question, although I decided to answer this. The reason is this is a common problem that beginner developers are facing. **The most important thing is this is related to almost all the programming languages. So, I'm giving this answer as a general answer for all the programming languages.** Let's go through them (dynamic array types) one by one.

**DYNAMIC ARRAYS**

Dynamic arrays AKA ArrayLists are arrays which don't have a fixed size. In another way, we can say they don't have a fixed amount of elements. We can allocate any amount of elements that we wish. No limits. We can do it when we initialize the dynamic array or we can do it later from time to time by adding elements one by one. The basic idea is that dynamic arrays haven't fixed size, we can add any amount of elements to dynamic arrays as we wish.

**DYNAMICALLY ALLOCATED ARRAYS**

Dynamically allocated arrays are almost similar to dynamic arrays. The main visible difference is when they are declared we have to give a size to them. But after that, if we want to exceed that size, we can do it without any problems. There will be no errors.

Eg: There is a dynamically allocated array with a size of 3. That means we are supposed to insert 3 elements into that array. But if we want to add more than 3 elements to that array, without any hesitation we can do that. (Keep in your mind that different languages have different ways to do it.)

**Importance of Dynamically Allocated Arrays**

In dynamically allocated arrays, we don't have to assign values to indexes in order. Usually, in arrays, we have to assign values like the below ones **if we add elements one by one**.

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
```

First, we should assign a value to the 0th index. Next, we should go in order like 1, 2, 3, ...

But, in dynamically allocated arrays, we can assign values as we wish. Like the below ones.

```
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[0] = 1;
```

You can see that I have assigned a value to the 1st index at first. Next, to the 2nd index. Finally, to the 0th index. No order at all. If you want to do this kind of thing, the dynamically allocated array is the best option.